# Click on span with padding

Tags: click, padding, html

I have a span with no text, it looks like an image, it has background and padding. But it doesnot execute onclick event. What to do? Do I need obviously change span to everything else?

Comment: Does it have an explicit height and width?

Comment: I put width and height in css, for test, but it ignore it, as it should

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention about display:block; check my answer again i edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need in spaces or anything, its working great without any changes, that was my bad!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there's something inside the span, e.g.:

```
<span>&nbsp;</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know if you want its background to be visible you need to set width and height for the span. And at least you need to include a space inside span

```
<span style='height:20px; width:100px; display:block;'> & n b s p ;</span>
```

Comment: I use span, as inline element

.container .header .remove {  
background: url(gfx/container/remove.png); 
padding: 1px 8px 2px 8px; margin: 5px; 
}